# How to perform a different action according to the time since hotkey has been pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I create an AutoHotkey script that when i press a specific hotkey it perform an action and when i press the same hotkey again if the time since the previous hotkey be < 1 sec, perform a different action?

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

F2::
  if () ; if time since previous F2 be < 1sec
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
return
```